# Thrusters dead, what do I do now?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Someone destroyed my thrusters while fighting them in space. I'm dead in the water now, and can't move at all. What do I do? Should I initiate a self-destruct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you get stuck in space, with dead thrusters, you might be able to repair them by initiating a reboot of your systems.

1. Go to your right-hand control panel (<kbd>4</kbd> key, by default, on PC version)
2. Go to <kbd>Functions</kbd>
3. Select the <kbd>Reboot / Repair</kbd> option

This should fix your thrusters, and get you back up and running, so you can visit a base or space station to repair your ship. If you self-destruct, you'll have to pay the insurance cost to replace your ship, which can be very expensive (5% of total ship cost) if you have a high-end ship and/or high-end components and you will permanently lose any NPC crew you have on board at the time. Try to avoid doing this, unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Note that reboot/repair completely powers ship down (including dropping shields) and pulls health away from other components to repair the ones that are at 0%. Also sometimes takes multiple tries to repair everything you need repaired.